# How do I replace XElement values using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, foreach

I have a XML and it contains multiple `<b>` tags. I want to remove some of them depending on the `XElement`. So if the `XElement` is `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<bq>` or `<fc>`, I want to remove the `<b>` tags from their respective values.

I am currently using `foreach` to do it and it works, but I want to go for just one `LINQ`.

This is my code:

```
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("h1"))
{
    if (item.Elements("b").Count() > 0)
    {
        itemvalue = item.Value.Replace("<b>", String.Empty).Replace("</b>",String.Empty);
        item.SetValue(itemvalue);
    }
}
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("h2"))
{
    if (item.Elements("b").Count() > 0)
    {
        itemvalue = item.Value.Replace("<b>", String.Empty).Replace("</b>",String.Empty);
        item.SetValue(itemvalue);
    }
}
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("h3"))
{
    if (item.Elements("b").Count() > 0)
    {
        itemvalue = item.Value.Replace("<b>", String.Empty).Replace("</b>",String.Empty);
        item.SetValue(itemvalue);
    }
}
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("bq"))
{
    if (item.Elements("b").Count() > 0)
    {
        itemvalue = item.Value.Replace("<b>", String.Empty).Replace("</b>",String.Empty);
        item.SetValue(itemvalue);
    }
}
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("fc"))
{
    if (item.Elements("b").Count() > 0)
    {
        itemvalue = item.Value.Replace("<b>", String.Empty).Replace("</b>",String.Empty);
        item.SetValue(itemvalue);
    }
}
```

I want something like:

```
xdoc.Descendants().Where(el => (el.Name.LocalName == "h1" || el.Name.LocalName == "h2" || el.Name.LocalName == "h3"
                            || el.Name.LocalName == "bq" || el.Name.LocalName == "fc") && el.Value.Contains("</b>"))...Replace;
```

Is is possible?

Comment: Please could you post sample input XML and the desired output? I'm surprised to hear that the element *value* contains `<b>`, as the value is meant to only be *text* content, not elements.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned. The respective element values will be having `<b>` tags and I want to remove the `<b>` tags from the values itself.

Comment: No, I think you've missed my point - they're not `<b>` tags if they're present in the *text* of the value. They'd be represented as `&lt;b&gt;` or similar. That's not a tag, it's in a text node. This is why I've asked for the XML input and expected output.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. But, even though I would love to use a non-string `(XElement)` approach, currently I see no other option. Anyway, this is my input `<h1><page num="3"/><b>Magie &amp; Wahrheit</b></h1>` and this will be my output `<h1><page num="3"/>Magie &amp; Wahrheit</h1>`. I surely can do I string replace but I really want to go `XElement`.

Comment: Please put this in your *question* as a [mcve]. But I wouldn't expect your current code to help with that XML at all, as `item.Value` will never contain `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine.(If you know what you are doing)

Would like to see the structure of your xml, though.

Anyways, currently, by looking at you code

it seems `<b>` is a direct children of `<h1>` (and others) and you are replacing the value(which also has `<b>` tag inside it)

I hope your structure is somewhat like

```
<h1>
    <b><b>xyz</b></b>
</h1>
```

then it will give

```
<h1>
    <b>xyz</b>
<h1>
```

## Linq

Maybe this will work...

```
 srcTree.Descendants().Where(el => (el.Name.LocalName == "h1" || el.Name.LocalName == "h2" || el.Name.LocalName == "h3"
                            || el.Name.LocalName == "bq" || el.Name.LocalName == "fc") && el.Value.Contains("</b>")).Select(x => x).ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetValue(x.Value.Replace("<b>", String.Empty).Replace("</b>", String.Empty)));
```

Comment: I will not be getting a `<b><b>` situation but I get your point. Also, is there no way to do it using a single LINQ?